# C# async, Stop all tasks when one is finished without the access to the code

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I'm writing a small application that uses Provider Model pattern in .NET. Each provider has one method to implement in order to plug-in in my application.

I want to run all providers' specific work (the implemented method) in different threads BUT when one task is finished all other tasks need to stop executing.

I am using async/await model in .NET with CancellationToken for cancelling a task.

```
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                            token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                        return provider.DoWork();

                }, token));

while (tasks.Count > 0)
        {
            var t = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);

            tasks.Remove(t);

            var result = await t;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
            {
                tokenSource.Cancel();
                return result;
            }
        }
```

Some of the provider.DoWork() methods can be very slow and to stop the thread in which DoWork method executes I have to check token.IsCancellationRequested within DoWork method but I can't because the methods are written from somebody else, for example. 
The check of token.IsCancellationRequested outside DoWork doesn't really matter in that case.

To sum up, when one task is finished, other tasks have to be stopped but without access to the code running in each thread.

Looking forward to hearing your thoughts about that.

Comment: "fastest provider wins" is a bit of an odd model, I have to say

Comment: If you can't trust the providers to be co-operative and periodically check the cancellation token, then I suspect you'll have to write code that manages the threads of the providers and aborts/interrupts the threads of the those providers you wish to stop.

Comment: @MarcGravell Imagine that providers are some html parsers to search for something, when one of it finds it and some other is waiting for response from a site for 5-10 seconds, why should I wait that 10 seconds. Actually with that code I (as a client) will see the search result but the tasks are not killed and CPU is on 100% unnecessary.

Comment: @DilyanDimitrov I can only advise you based on reality: if those tasks don't support cancellation correctly, that is the fault of the implementation

Comment: @EiríkurFannarTorfason there simply isn't any recommendable way of interrupting threads

Comment: @MarcGravell So... I can extend my provider base class to have Token for example, but that way I transfer responsibility on cancelling the task in providers, which I don't want. What are my options here ?

Comment: @DilyanDimitrov well, you can already ignore the results of anything that is too slow; it sounds like your main concern is bad providers... frankly, I'd be tempted to keep track of the times of each, and simply cull any that are routinely too slow and which fail to respond to cancellation: that should motivate them to implement it correctly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several different possible ways to stop arbitrary code, none of which are ideal.

First, you can approach this on a thread level. In other words, give each provider a separate thread and call `Thread.Abort` when you want it to stop. Unfortunately, there is a whole myriad of problems with this approach: two of the more well-known issues are a possibility of deadlock, and entering an odd state where a type can no longer be instantiated in your AppDomain. For this reason, `Thread.Abort` is considered "evil" and a definite code smell.

Moving one level higher, you can approach this on an AppDomain level. In this case, you give each provider a separate AppDomain. The advantage of this approach is that you can shut down an AppDomain more cleanly than you can a thread. Unfortunately, some things can still slip through the cracks: in particular, unmanaged resources can leak into your process from an AppDomain.

Which leaves you with the most reliable solution: approaching this on a process level. That is, you give each provider a separate process and use inter-process communication to control it. A process can be shut down cleanly, since the OS is responsible for cleaning up. Unfortunately, this approach has the most overhead and is the most difficult to program.

A robust hosting solution must support at least the last one. ASP.NET, for example, supports all three: request threads can be aborted in some situations (e.g., the client disconnects), the AppDomain can be recycled, and this be escalated to where the entire worker process is recycled. However, I recommend that you do not write your own hosting platform with escalation policies.

What I recommend is to 1) provide the `CancellationToken` to your providers and encourage them to use it, and 2) after you signal the token, just let them run to completion.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. My main concerns about passing CancellationToken to providers are: 1) that way I create some kind of a connection between how providers implemented and the context in which they executed (async, sync, etc). 2) providers must know what is CancellationToken and how to use it. 3) a provider which not dealing properly with the Token may slow the whole system (solution: as @Marc said - ignoring slow providers or set some kind of timeout). In the other hand, when you use external library or API you should find out how to use it, right.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by (1); `CancellationToken` is the standard cancellation mechanism for both synchronous and asynchronous code. I think (2) is not a difficult proposition. And as far as (3) goes, the *only* reliable way to manage stupid code is in a separate process.

Answer (score 2):

There are a myriad of problems associated with abruptly terminating a thread in a process - essentially, that should only be done as a last resort when the process is so sickly that you're about to kill the entire thing anyway. Anything other than that, and you're at grave risk of causing significant problems if you interfere. So: that leaves graceful elective exit. You mention that you are already using cancellation tokens; really, that's all you can do (safely, at least). It is up to the different implementations to check for cancellation and exit. If you can't rely on the tasks periodically checking for cancellation: you are a bit stuck.

Basically, there is no easy answer to what you describe.